# Extract characters after particular pattern in r

Tags: r

I have a column in which i want to extract characters which are before x from right hand side. Sample strings in column is **ABCDx1234xaP_solution**. I need to extract **aP_solution**.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using `sub` could be to remove everything until last `'x'`.

```
sub('.*x', '', 'ABCDx1234xaP_solution')
#[1] "aP_solution"
```

Comment: Much better than mine, I forgot that regex's are greedy.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will do it.

```
x <- "ABCDx1234xaP_solution"

sub("^.*x([^x]+$)", "\\1", x)
#[1] "aP_solution"
```